# Maybe monad what is Just for?

Tags: c#, monads

I have been reading up on how to implement monads in C#. In the more Haskell like implementations such as the one described [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/01/monads-in-c-5-maybe.html) use a type called `Just` to wrap a result other than "`Nothing`".  Is this type only a convenience so that we do not have to keep saying `Maybe` everywhere in our code or does it have some other property that I am not understanding?  An [implementation](http://ericlippert.com/2013/03/21/monads-part-nine/) by Eric Lippert does not use a type called `Just` and instead returns `Tainted<R>` for example.

Comment: I believe that `Tainted` example is a different monad than the `Maybe` example.

Comment: I find this kind of implementation (using a interface and classes a bit missleading - a more 1:1 implementation is IMHO like this: https://github.com/CarstenKoenig/DWX2014/blob/master/Monads/Monaden%20Solution/Monaden.CSharp/Maybe/Maybe.cs (in case you miss the `return` in there - it's just the `Some` - this was intendet to demonstrate how you could implment LINQ syntax features and compare it to F#/Haskell so I might have some unfortunate mixing of Names (Some vs Just) (Maybe vs Option) in there :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite declaring `Just` as a class in C#, it is technically not a type. In Haskell parlance, `Just` is called a data constructor; it creates data of type `Maybe`. Similarly, `Nothing` is also a data constructor.

In Haskell, `Maybe` is used as a simple error handling mechanism. `Just` indicates that the wrapped value is the result of an operation whereas `Nothing` indicates an error of some kind. As a basic example, Haskell has a function with the following signature(1):

```
lookup :: [(key, value)] -> key -> Maybe value
```

This `lookup` function takes a list of (key, value) pairs and a key and returns a value wrapped in a `Maybe`. If the key exists, then the associated value is wrapped in a `Just`, otherwise a `Nothing` is returned.

(1) I have intentionally left out a detail that is irrelevant to this discussion.

`Tainted` from Eric Lippert's article looks like another example of a `Monad`, but is completely different from the `Maybe` monad. I don't think it is useful trying to compare the two other than the similarities from the monad pattern.

Comment: good answer! I tend to use `Maybe`/`Option` whatever you will call it when the function is *partial* or when there is only one reason to *fail* - that is there are some inputs that just don't have any meaningful output (the `lookup` is a good example) - and use `Either String` when I want there are more reasons to fail with a reason) (of course you can view every function to be total if you include the errors/bottom in the output-type so this is all a bit philosophical)